# orgmode agenda view doesn´t display any results

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I´m new to emacs and especially org-mode, and I am testing it´s different possibilies. When trying the schedule-function with `TODO`, I don´t get any results displayed in the weekly or daily list.

```
 * TODO Get schwifty
 SCHEDULED: <2017-09-03 So>
```

I then set the global-keys as it is recommended in the manual with C-c a to reach the weekly schedule, but I only get a blank list of weekdates with no content. What´s wrong?

Comment: Have you added the file containing this scheduled event to the agenda file list with `org-agenda-file-to-front`?

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Just hit `C-c [` to make this happen. In the videos I was watching people had always already done that, so I missed the point. If you can update your comment to an answer, I can mark this as an answer. Where is the agenda-file list saved?

Comment: Someone please post the answer as an answer (which can be accepted by the OP). Thx.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In order for org-mode to show events scheduled or with a deadline in the agenda-view, the org-file containing these events must be listed in the variable `org-agenda-files`. While one can customize this variable, the more practical way is to invoke the function `org-agenda-file-to-front`, which is commonly bound to `C-c [`.

For further details see the org-mode manual: [Agenda files](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Agenda-files)

Comment: `org-agenda-file-to-front` is bound to `C-c [` by default, not `C-c ]`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this answer will help future Doom Emacs users who run into this problem.

I think it had to do with the order in which multiple configuration files are loaded.  My solution was to put the following in `config.el`:

```
(after! org
  (setq org-agenda-files '("~/org/inbox.org"
                          "~/org/gtd.org"
                          "~/org/tickler.org")))
```

The `after! org ...)` is the important bit.  It will set the property *after* going into org mode, whereas, I believe, Doom is setting its own default location on startup.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a ':' in front of SCHEDULE.
So it would become 
 :SCHEDULED: <2017-09-03 So>
I had a similar problem and this solved it.
However if there are any side effect, I am not aware.
Someone may like to comment on this.

Comment: Welcom to emacs.stackexchange. Note that in this case the solution was adding the file to org-agenda-files as described in the accepted answer. Adding ':' is not necessary and will not help if org-agenda is not aware of the file. I'm not sure what was going on in your case.

Comment: I found that I needed the extra `:` in the case of

`** TODO Improve emacs/org skills`
`:SCHEDULED: <2021-04-28 Wed .+1d>`

for an item that was in a file that the Agenda knows about.  So satish's answer may be helpful if someone runs into the same issue!

Comment: However, after discussion on IRC, they clarified to me that it really is `SCHEDULED:` and I found some bogus code in my startup file that was breaking the normal behaviour.